# Where did General Grievous first make himself known to the Jedi in the Disney Canon?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, general-grievous

In the EU it was in the 20th chapter of the [2003 Clone Wars animated microseries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_Clone_Wars_(2003_TV_series)). Where does Grievous first reveal himself in the Disney canon?

Note I'm not asking about his first appearance in general, but when the Jedi first met him (and lived to report it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Unknown

The chronologically first *appearance* of Grievous appears to be "Rising Malevolence," Episode 1.02 of the *Clone Wars* (2008 series)

In "Rising Malevolence," Count Dooku is seen commanding the warship *Malevolence* and its powerful superweapon.

The chronological order of the various *Clone Wars* episodes is laid out in [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/100260/51379). "Rising Malevolence" was preceded by:

- 2.16    "Cat and Mouse"
- 1.16    "Hidden Enemy"
- *The Clone Wars* movie
- 3.01    "Clone Cadets"
- 3.03    "Supply Lines"
- 1.01    "Ambush"

None of these episodes features General Grievous.

**However, we know the Jedi Order must have have known about him earlier**, because they are there when Palpatine speaks of the ion cannon as "General Grievous's secret weapon":

> PALPATINE: Have you had any success in finding General Grievous's secret weapon?
>   Master Plo was here in the Abregado system when we lost contact.

It therefore seems likely, though not certain, that some Jedi had encountered him prior to the events of this episode.

There's no indication, to my knowledge, of what he was doing prior to "Rising Malevolence."

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I guess this will open up a potential new story in the Disney canon, although I don't know how they'll top his appearance in the microseries -- that was one of the best entrances ever.