# Order of the unreleased Clone Wars

Tags: star-wars, suggested-order, the-clone-wars

I want to watch the ***unreleased*** Clone Wars, but I'm not sure of a specific order there may be to watch it in. I am fully aware that the released ones are out of order and I'm afraid these may be too.

Comment: This may be a valid source for the episodes https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zAe5Ogs6a-c - The correct sequence for some a four-episode arc that was never finished. You can watch "A Death on Utapau," "In Search of the Crystal," "Crystal Crisis," and "The Big Bang" at StarWars.com.

Comment: @EnigmaMaitreya Can you put your answer in an answer, please?

Comment: Actually, based on Rogue Jedi's answer and the info above, it seems like the unreleased episodes _are_ included under the "Reels" section of [Rogue's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/100260/31178)

Comment: @CreationEdge I am not sure this is a duplicate of that question as that question is entirely different. It is asking for an opinion on IF one should watch them in release sequence or arc sequence. This is asking for a sequence of unreleased, unfinished, episodes.

Comment: Which unreleased clone wars are you asking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry it took this long to come back and do this right.

Hum, it has been suggested that the links can not be verified as "legal"(per Ixrec), so I am removing the links. The Titles of the Episode are certainly Google Worthy.

**Star Wars The Clone Wars Story Reel #1 A Death on Utapau**

**Star Wars The Clone Wars Story Reel #2 In Search of the Crystal**

**Star Wars The Clone Wars Story Reel #3 Crystal Crisis**

**Star Wars The Clone Wars Story Reel #4 The Big Bang"**

**Star Wars The Clone Wars Story Reel #5 The Bad Batch**

**Star Wars The Clone Wars Story Reel #6 A Distant Echo**

**Star Wars The Clone Wars Story Reel #7 On The Wings Of Keeradaks**

**Star Wars The Clone Wars Story Reel #8 Unfinished Business**

I enjoyed this **Evolution of Ahsoka Tano**